# Missing dev tools context menus in Edge insider build

Tags: microsoft-edge, developer-tools

I just updated to the Windows Insider Preview [Build #14328](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/04/22/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14328-for-pc-and-mobile/) and can't find the *Inspect Element* or *View Source* context menu options in Microsoft Edge to open the F12 Developer Tools. Where have they gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Inspect Element` and `View Source` context menus are now hidden by default in Edge. To bring them back open the F12 developer tools either from the `…` (more) menu or by using the F12 key. Once you open the tools for the first time the context menu items will be added back.

You can also add the context menus back by navigating Edge to `about:flags` and checking the `Show Inspect Element and View Source context menus`.

Comment: I'm having dev tools open almost all the time, yet I didnt figure this out. Thanks. There is no "Show Inspect Element and View Source context menus" in my edge.